# Magento 2 manual Installation

Tags: magento2, composer, magento-upgrade, composer-update

Whenever we install magento by downloading magento zip(Manually), Magento core modules are stored in app/code/magento folder.
How magento update works when we want to upgrade older versions to new version using composer update command?
After completion of update do we need to remove app/code/magento ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain your installation with composer you also need to install with composer. You can do that by following these instructions —

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/composer.html?lang=en

It is noted on this page that "*Developers contributing to Magento Open Source should use the git-based installation method.*" If you are working on production sites and not contributing code then stick with composer.